# Django: Como agregar campos a un modelo desde otro modulo

Tags: django, django-models

He trabajado con un ERP (Open Object) en el cual se agregan módulos que afectan modelos de módulos de los cuales dependen permitiendo agregar funciones y campos. En django algo similar es posible a través del Meta.proxy pero este limita la posibilidad de crear nuevos campos. Revisando la estructura solo permite crear campos virtuales, los cuales imagino no se incluyen en la base de datos.

Mi idea es emular el comportamiento de este framework (Open Object) permitiendo agregar módulos opcionales que agreguen lógica y campos a modelos existentes. Esto me permitirá mantener mis módulos relativamente aislados permitiéndome desinstalarlos sin tener campos innecesarios en el modelo que afectan.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es algo amplia, pero dependiendo de lo que necesites, puedo recomendarte de entrada dos opciones, que a mi parecer pudieran ayudarte

La primera es trabajar con clases abstractas, que te den una estrucutura base con las cuales pudes crear clases que hereden de estas

miapp1/models.py

```
    class ModeloBase(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True
```

miapp2/models.py

```
    from miapp1.models import *

    class Persona(ModeloBase):
        campo1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        campo2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        class Meta:
            db_table = "app2_persona"
```

Lo anterior creara la tabla *app2_persona* en base de datos con las columnas especificadas en *ModeloBase* y en  *Persona*

La segunda opción es crear los modelos (sin que el padre sea abstracto) y heredarlos, con la diferencia que se crearan dos tablas en base de datos, una para el modelo padre y otra para el modelo hijo, al momento de almacenar los registros, los valores correspondientes al modelo padre, irán a la tabla del modelo padre, y en la tabla del modelo hijo se alamacenaran los campos correspondientes a este y tendras un campo que enlaza con el registro alamcenado en el modelo padre

miapp1/models.py

```
    class ModeloBase(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

miapp2/models.py

```
    from miapp1.models import *

    class Persona(ModeloBase):
        campo1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        campo2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Y de igual forma creas objetos desde persona y puedes acceder a los atributos del modelo padre, desde este objeto

```
    persona = Persona()
    persona.name = "Mi nombre"
    persona.save()
```

Comment: Quiero extender la pregunta a "Existe algo como el Try..Catch para validar que la app1 esté instalada y sinó definir el modelo base (al menos abstracto) en app2"?